How to set a maximum time limit for executing Java SimpleJdbcCall query?
I want to set a maximum time limit for executing a SimpleJdbcCall query to an Oracle 19 database from a Java 11 application. If the time is exceeded, the operation should be aborted.
How does this setting work and what could prevent it from functioning correctly?
Spring Boot: 2.5.7
ojdbc10: 19.22.0.0
I tried using the parameter:
spring.jdbc.template.query-timeout: 1m,
but it didn't work.
I also tried directly:
JdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout(60), but it also doesn't produce results.
